# I can not import IDs or restore my accounts from Microsoft Authenticator - How I can fix this?

Tags: security, restore, microsoft-authenticator

Because of a problem I need to import IDs and I entered the 12 words recovery phrase as one long string but I always get error from jwt file say file is encrypted.

I tried also to use my main email account from Microsoft but when I choose begin recovery it display that account does not has a backup !! I tried also all my emails same result. I dont know how I can restore my accounts. Any ideas ?